# О шестом флоте США и прописной букве

Tags: орфография, прописная-строчная, названия

Что такое шестой флот США и почему он пишется в новостях с большой буквы?
Есть ли основания для этого?
Шестой флот США (англ. *United States Sixth Fleet*) — оперативный флот американских военно-морских сил, дислоцирующийся в Средиземном море (из Википедии).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Думаю, такие основания есть.
**Шестой** флот ВМС США иногда ещё называют **Средиземноморским**, потому что именно там он и находится.
С флотами России всё понятно: Северный, Балтийский, Черноморский, Тихоокеанский, Каспийская флотилия.

В состав Тихоокеанского флота ВМС США входят три оперативных флота: 3-й, 7-й и 5-й.
Каждому из флотов дать "географическую привязку" невозможно (например, Третий флот находится на территории восточной и северной частей Тихого океана, включает Берингово море, Алеутские острова, Аляску и зону Арктики), поэтому их просто *сосчитали*.

Вот что разъясняет ["Грамота"](http://new.gramota.ru/biblio/readingroom/rules/139-prop):

> § 102. В названиях исторических событий, эпох и явлений, а также исторических документов, произведений искусства и иных вещественных памятников с прописной буквы пишется первое слово, а также входящие в их состав имена собственные.
> Сюда относятся названия, выражаемые:
> в) любым иным сочетанием с начальным прилагательным или **числительным**, например: *Долгий парламент, Смутное время, Великая хартия вольностей, **Сто дней, Семилетняя война, Третья республика**, Июльская монархия, Великая Октябрьская социалистическая революция, Великая Отечественная война.*

Можно сравнить с названием улиц: Первый проезд, Вторая улица Энтузиастов, Третья улица Строителей (дом 25, квартира 12; помните?).

Флагман Шестого флота США покидает Чёрное море.
В израильский порт прибывают корабли Шестого флота США...